# How can I implement asynchronous rabbitmq client pika or pyrabbit in celery task?

Tags: python, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery, pika

I'm using `celery` and `rabbitmq` to process around 10 million tasks. The output of the task is a json that is stored in a remote rabbitmq. I was using `Pika` to publish the message to different queues in the remote rabbitmq. Currently I'm getting this error `pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection` as pika is not asynchronous. I found another asynchronous client [pyrabbit](http://pyrabbit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) . But I'm not able to implement it in my code. Do I need to create a new connection for every task ? Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from test_celery.celery import app
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'pass')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('myip',5672,'/',credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()

@app.task(bind=True,default_retry_delay=10,time_limit=22)
def get_data(self,url):
    ..# Processing code
    message = json.dumps(data)
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',routing_key=country,          
                    body=message,
                    properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode = 2,))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a tested answer for you, but in regards to your question "Do I need to create a new connection for every task?" that is generally bad performance wise and the usual solution is a connection pool.  I did a quick search and came across https://github.com/bninja/pika-pool which might possibly help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your connection has been set as global variable for the module. I have found that it eventually does close when used as such.

My work around for this has been to create a separate 'publisher' module which is called by the task. This ensures that the connection remains fresh.

That said, it sounds like you are churning a lot of data. You should be able to check if the connection is open using `connection.is_open` which returns `True` if it is in open. If it is not open...then reconnect.

So, maybe this would work:

```
def connect():
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'pass')
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('myip',5672,'/',credentials)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    return connection, channel

connection, channel = connect()

@app.task(bind=True,default_retry_delay=10,time_limit=22)
def get_data(self,url):
    ..# Processing code
    message = json.dumps(data)

    if connection.is_open == False:
        connection, channel = connect()

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',routing_key=country,          
                    body=message,
                    properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode = 2,))
```

Hope that helps...